# How to make a hidden face appear from the top using -webkit-transform: rotateX();

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to do this 3D transformation effect using `css` `transform` :

[image]

In my attempt the hidden face appears from the right while it needs to appear from the bottom in mouse hover, I don't know what i'm doing wrong , any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for your feedback.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QMQLQ/294/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
            <img src='http://placehold.it/180x180/' alt=''>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
            <img src='http://placehold.it/180x180/' alt=''>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box-scene {
    -webkit-perspective: 700;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;

    z-index: 999;
}
.box-scene:hover .box {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
.box {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 90px -90px -90px;

    /* float: left; */
    margin: 30px auto;


}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible; 

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    background: #d9d9d9;
}
.side {
    background: #9dcc78;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hidden face shall come from the bottom, you have to change its position and some of the initial rotation. Here's the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMQLQ/295/).
If you want it to come from the side the only thing to change is replacing `rotateX(-90deg)` with `rotateY(-90deg)` for the `.box-scene:hover .box` part. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMQLQ/296/).